# Find roots for an integral function

Tags: r, functional-programming, numerical-integration

I am writing a function in R to find the root k for function

[image]

where the \phi(x) is probability density for standard normal distribution.

Here is what I have done

```
fn = function(l1,l2,kappa){
  intf = function(x){
    2*((l1*x+l2)^kappa)*dnorm(x)
  }
  return(intf)
}

g = function(l1,l2){
  function(kappa){
    integrate(fn(l1,l2,kappa),0,Inf)-1
  }
}

m = function(l1,l2){
  kk = g(l1,l2) 
  inter = c(1,5)
  res = uniroot(kk,c(1,5))
  return(res$root)
}
```

But I got an error message says that

```
> m(0.08,0.09)
rror in integrate(fn(l1, l2, kappa), 0, Inf) - 1 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

And if I change my function `g` to

```
g = function(l1,l2){
  function(kappa){
    integrate(fn(l1,l2,kappa),0,Inf)
  }
}
```

The error message is

```
> m(0.08,0.09)
 Error in pmin(x, .Machine$double.xmax) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' 
In addition:     Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be u
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks!

Comment: The integrate function returns a list. You need to add `$value` to the integrate call result. You also need to figure out what to do with kappa.

Comment: @42- Thank you so much! You have save my life! It is working now!

Comment: Seems that a trivial solution would be `l1`=0, `l2`=2 and `kappa` = 1.

Comment: @42- Yes, but I am writing a function to find the tail index of a GARCH model, so I need to find the exact `kappa` for specific `l1` and `l2`.

Comment: I'm glad it worked in your hands. I wasn't able to get a solution.